# Joining tables in the without pk/fk values & using dates & inferring data model

Tags: sql, join

Below is a query you can run in [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6fcded/7) to create a schema. I am trying to infer who managers are and how to run a query that shows employees hired before managers

```
CREATE TABLE Departments (
    dept_no VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    dept_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Departments (dept_no, dept_name) VALUES
    ('d009', 'Customer Service');
CREATE TABLE Dept_emp (
    EMP_NO INT NOT NULL,
    DEPT_NO VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    FROM_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    TO_DATE DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Dept_emp (EMP_NO, DEPT_NO, FROM_DATE, TO_DATE) VALUES
    (10001, 'd005', '1986-06-26', '9999-01-01'),
    (10002, 'd007', '1996-08-03', '9999-01-01');
CREATE TABLE Dept_manager (
    EMP_NO INT NOT NULL,
    DEPT_NO VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    FROM_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    TO_DATE DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Dept_manager (EMP_NO, DEPT_NO, FROM_DATE, TO_DATE) VALUES
    (110022, 'd001', '1985-01-01', '1991-10-01');
CREATE TABLE Employees (
    EMP_NO INT NOT NULL,
    BIRTH_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    GENDER CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    HIRE_DATE DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Employees (EMP_NO, BIRTH_DATE, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, GENDER, HIRE_DATE) VALUES
    (1, '1977-06-14', 'Geert', 'Vanderkelen', 'M', '2018-04-22'),
    (10001, '1953-09-02', 'Georgi', 'Facello', 'M', '1986-06-26');
CREATE TABLE Salaries (
    EMP_NO INT NOT NULL,
    SALARY INT NOT NULL,
    FROM_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    TO_DATE DATE NOT NULL
);

-- Insert your sample data into the Salaries table here
CREATE TABLE Titles (
    EMP_NO INT NOT NULL,
    TITLE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    FROM_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    TO_DATE DATE NOT NULL
);

-- Insert your sample data into the Titles table here

INSERT INTO Departments (dept_no, dept_name) VALUES
    ('d001', 'Human Resources'),
    ('d002', 'Finance'),
    ('d003', 'Marketing'),
    ('d004', 'Engineering'),
    ('d005', 'Sales');
    
    INSERT INTO Dept_emp (EMP_NO, DEPT_NO, FROM_DATE, TO_DATE) VALUES
    (10003, 'd001', '1992-05-05', '9999-01-01'),
    (10004, 'd002', '1994-06-15', '9999-01-01'),
    (10005, 'd003', '1995-04-12', '9999-01-01'),
    (10006, 'd004', '1997-10-17', '9999-01-01'),
    (10007, 'd005', '1999-12-24', '9999-01-01');
    
    INSERT INTO Employees (EMP_NO, BIRTH_DATE, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, GENDER, HIRE_DATE) VALUES
    (10008, '1980-03-25', 'Sarah', 'Johnson', 'F', '2000-08-10'),
    (10009, '1975-12-19', 'Michael', 'Smith', 'M', '2001-02-15'),
    (10010, '1982-09-30', 'Emily', 'Davis', 'F', '2002-04-20'),
    (10011, '1978-06-08', 'David', 'Anderson', 'M', '2003-07-05'),
    (10012, '1985-01-14', 'Jennifer', 'Brown', 'F', '2004-09-30');
    
    INSERT INTO Salaries (EMP_NO, SALARY, FROM_DATE, TO_DATE) VALUES
    (10003, 60000, '1992-05-05', '1999-12-31'),
    (10004, 75000, '1994-06-15', '1999-12-31'),
    (10005, 80000, '1995-04-12', '1999-12-31'),
    (10006, 90000, '1997-10-17', '1999-12-31'),
    (10007, 85000, '1999-12-24', '1999-12-31');

INSERT INTO Titles (EMP_NO, TITLE, FROM_DATE, TO_DATE) VALUES
    (10003, 'Manager', '1992-05-05', '1999-12-31'),
    (10004, 'Director', '1994-06-15', '1999-12-31'),
    (10005, 'Senior Manager', '1995-04-12', '1999-12-31'),
    (10006, 'Engineer', '1997-10-17', '1999-12-31'),
    (10007, 'Analyst', '1999-12-24', '1999-12-31');
```

my query attempt below is trying to see what employees were hired before their manager, without using emp_no ( corrupt data) and infering who a manger is.

Wondering if anyone could help me finalize infering this data model and hepling put the query over the finish line to answer the question above.

Current query not working:

```
with md as (SELECT 
  e.EMP_NO AS employee_emp_no,
  e.FIRST_NAME AS employee_first_name,
  e.LAST_NAME AS employee_last_name,
  de.DEPT_NO,
  de.from_date de_from_date,
  de.to_date de_to_date,
  dm.from_date as dm_from_date,
  dm.dept_no,
  dm.emp_no as manager_id,
  s.salary
FROM employees e
LEFT JOIN dept_emp de ON e.EMP_NO = de.EMP_NO
LEFT JOIN departments d ON de.DEPT_NO = d.DEPT_NO
LEFT JOIN dept_manager dm ON de.FROM_DATE  = dm.FROM_DATE  and de.to_date = dm.to_date  
left join  salaries s on e.emp_no = s.emp_no
where manager_id is not null )
select distinct e.EMP_NO, e.FIRST_NAME, e.LAST_NAME 
from employees e
LEFT JOIN dept_emp de ON e.EMP_NO = de.EMP_NO
left join md on e.EMP_NO = md.employee_emp_no
where e.hire_date < md.dm_from_date ;
```

Comment: Focus, don't select a lot of columns in the cte that are never used.

Comment: `md.dm_from_date` in the WHERE clause makes the left join return regular inner join result. Move that condition to the ON clause to get true left join result.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "without using emp_no ( corrupt data) and infering who a manger is". If your data is corrupt then you need to fix it - how are you expecting to join tables using columns that contain corrupt data?